# Data-widget tree problem in fa fa-angle-left pull-right in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, font-awesome, adminlte

I have a problem in **fa fa-angle-left pull-right** once click not working in down angle.
**I am using Admin LTE**
I don't know why it's not working and what is the main issue of this.

[image: screen shot of the issue]

HTML:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
        <li class="header">HEADER</li>
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Multilevel</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

JS:

```
newSp.component('newSpSideBar', {
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        controller: function (svc) {
            var ctrl = this;
            ctrl.siteUrl = svc.getSiteUrl();
            ctrl.tempUrl = svc.getTemplateUrl('main-sidebar.html');
        },
        template: "<div ng-include='vm.tempUrl'></div>",
        bindings: {
            title: '@'
        }
    });
```

Comment: Seems like your problem is with styling. Edit the question and create a code snippet to describe the problem.

Comment: cannot do snippet due to the massive code needed if creating snippet

Comment: The question is not clear enough, you want to toggle the arrow with respect to collapse and expand?

Comment: yes basically the arrow pull down if the menu expand

Answer (score 0):

After some research I got the answer. I found out that there's something wrong with my class **fa fa-angle-left pull-right** I compared to the example of admin LTE dashboard does not match.

So I copy ***AdminLTE.css*** and replace to my code which is **AdminLTE v2.4.6** to **AdminLTE v2.4.18**

Hope it helps for someone who got experience this issue.